# Can I carry someone else's driving extracts from India to Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I am travelling to Canada. One of my colleague wants to apply for a Driving License. So he requested me to get his Driving Extract (It's a document which tells about your driving history, meaning if there are any offenses registered).

Can I carry this document with me?

Comment: If it is many thousands of pages, you may run into weight limits.

Comment: No it's just 4 pages.

Comment: Then I can't imagine what would be a problem.

Comment: The only reasons I see paperwork can be an issue is if it shows an intent to break visa rules (e.g. you intend to immigrate/work in a country you’re supposed to be just visiting), or of course national security (e.g. plans for a terrotist plot). Other than that, you can bring in any paperwork you want, and in this case I definitely can’t see any issue.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's a police document of someone's driving record. In many countries it's required to obtain car liability insurance. I see no problem with carrying them, especially if he can't wait to receive them in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can carry personal papers for other people.
They might be inspected if you get a very thorough check (which is very rare) but even then they are nothing to worry about.

If you want to take an explanation why you bring these papers, print out an e-mail in which your friend asks you to bring them.